# react-loadable import from multiple class exported js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, code-splitting, react-loadable

How to import from a multiple class exported `js` file in `react-loadable`.
I am trying to import `CustomButton` from `MyButton.js` using `react-loadable` in `Home.js`. This is the only way I know to do it, is not working.

### MyButton.js

```
import {
  CustomButton,
  BUTTON_STYLE,
  BUTTON_TYPE,
  BUTTON_SIZE,
  BUTTON_ALIGN,
  COLOR
} from './buttons';
module.exports = {
  CustomButton,
  BUTTON_STYLE,
  BUTTON_TYPE,
  BUTTON_SIZE,
  BUTTON_ALIGN,
  COLOR
}
```

### Home.js

```
const AsyncButton = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('../../button/MyButton'),
  loading: Loading
});
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to do it this way:

```
const AsyncButton = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('../../button/MyButton').then(module => module.CustomButton),
  loading: Loading
});
```

However, I can't get it where one variable contains all the other exports.

Answer (score 5):

I Found a solution from

[react-loadable documentation](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable/blob/master/README.md)

```
Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./my-component'),
  render(loaded, props) {
    let Component = loaded.namedExport;
    return <Component {...props}/>;
  }
});
```

Its working.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is answered, but I came up with a way around getting one variable to contain all named exports. See below.

```
    AsyncSubSites = namedComponent => Loadable({
    loader: () =>
      import( /*webpackChunkName: "SubSites"*/ "./SubSites/SubSites"),
    loading: () => <Loading/>, //loader/spinner etc.
    modules: ["SubSites"],
    render(loaded, props) {
      let Component = loaded[namedComponent];
      return <Component {...props}/>;
    }
  })
```

and used with react-router as...

```
<Route path="/:slug" exact component={AsyncSubSites('Membership')} />
<Route path="/:slug" exact component={AsyncSubSites('About')} />
```

and whatever other named export